# Don`t load Map in MapActivity

Tags: java, android, google-play

I made an Activity class that I implemented from a MapActivity with final key to Google Maps, but when I published to Android Market my app don`t load maps correctly.

What I need to do?

Comment: Do you have a grey grid? When you run the signed app in debug mode (on emulator or phone), does it show the map?

Comment: Did you get both your debug Google Map key and your release key?

Comment: Maybe I am using a key that I generated in other machine and I compiled  my app with this key. I need to generate my app on the same machine that I generated the final key (maps) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem generating a new key for Google Maps based on my new Key. You can't reuse a key from GMaps if you generated a new Key to sign your app.